# how to display an html element which is display:none at certain media screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media

I have heading which i want to show at certain screen size. for bigger screen size i used display:none But for small screen how can make same div visible.
Please help.

```
@media screen and (max-width:960px){
   mydiv {display:none;}
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px){
   mydiv {visibility: visible;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the second line to this.

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){ mydiv {display: block;} }
```

For hide/show we normally use `display:none;` and `display:block;`

We can also use `visibility:hidden;` and `visibility:visible;`

But `display` and `visibility` are totally different properties. Most importantly - if a box is set to `visibility:hidden;` (it will be fully transparent, nothing is drawn), **but** still affects layout.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px){
    .mydiv{display:none;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .mydiv{display:block;}
}
```

Visibility still affects your layout, and the element is still there, but just not *visible*, whereas display:none hides the element all together.

Also make sure when you are referencing the class of your element you are placing a . before the name or else it doesn't know what class you are referring to.